# Fear-free guide to getting started has fear-inducing 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

When new users sign up for Stack Overflow, they get an email with the subject "Your friendly, fear-free guide to getting started". At the bottom it links to various SO services:

[image: "Open to new opportunities? Set your job search status"]

The link to "Set your job search status" is a 404 now, since SO Jobs is no more. It links to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current?utm_source=Iterable&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=gen-welcome-email&utm_content=aug18`.

Comment: You'd think they would have remembered to remove links like that as part of the deprecation...

Comment: We have different methods of sending out emails; this email in particular isn't sent from our codebase so it was missed when we did a global search. We'll look for it in our third-party service (which doesn't have a global search) and update the content for it. Thank you for finding this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you so much for finding this and reporting it! As I mentioned in my comment, we have different ways of sending out automated emails; this particular email is sent using a third-party service where we can't do a global search, so it's a bit harder keeping the email inventory up to date on there.

Anyways, we have updated this email template and have gotten rid of the broken link!